# Unable to send data to php from jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to PHP using JQuery ajax. However, I am only able to the send the first `key=value` to PHP, the second `key=value` echo as blank.

For example:

```
functionName="+env works but not username="+username;
```

How can I pass multiple key value pair to PHP from JQuery AJAX?

**Jquery AJAX**

```
var envdata="functionName="+env+",username="+username;
alert(envdata);


if(action == 'R'){
  $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'getdata.php',
data: envdata,
success: function(response) {
                $("#textarea_message").val(response);

}
```

**getdata.php**

```
$env = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'functionName');
echo $env
$username = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'username');
echo $username;
```

Comment: The string is improperly formed, it needs to be like a query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building your `data` wrong. it's basically equivalent to a URL query string, which means you need to use `&` as the separator, not a `,`:

```
var envdata="functionName="+env+"&username="+username;
                                 ^---note the &
```

commas mean nothing to PHP as far as url query arguments go, so your `,username=foo` would become part of the `functionname` value.

A simple `var_dump($_GET)` would show you exactly what PHP is seeing come in. Doing that should've been your first stop when you didn't get your expected data in the script.

Answer (score -1):

Read about JSON

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#some_button').on('click', function() {
    var checks = new Array();
    $("input[name='ls_id']:checked").each(function() {checks.push($(this).val());});
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "some url",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                data: {checks: checks, func: 9},
                success: function(data) {
                }
            });
});
```

});

getdata:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['checks'], true);
        print_r ($json);
```